# Making the height of an element equal to a div

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to make the height of '.caption' to be the same as '.post'.

The problem is that I have a lot of '.post' divs with different heights.

This is what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var postH = $('.post').height();
    $('.caption').css( "height", postH );
});
```

It works but only for the first element, the rest of the elements remain with the height of the first '.caption'.

Thank you!

EDIT:

HTML Structure:

```
<div class="content">

    <div class="entry">
        <div class="post">...</div>
        <div class="caption">...</div>
    </div>

    <div class="entry">
        <div class="post">...</div>
        <div class="caption">...</div>
    </div>

    <div class="entry">
        <div class="post">...</div>
        <div class="caption">...</div>
    </div>

    <div class="entry">
        <div class="post">...</div>
        <div class="caption">...</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

UPDATE:

I finally found a solution:

```
$('.entry').each(function() {
    $(this).height( $(this).find('.post').height() + 80 );
});
```

I set the overflow of '.entry' to be hidden. The '+ 80' is because the '.post' has a padding of 40.

Comment: dont use height as a css parameter. use `$('.caption').height($('.post').height());`

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't work.. The height applies only for the first one, I don't know why

Comment: Can we see just a short example of your HTML markup?

Comment: Yes, I updated with the markup, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand well, you have many post and many caption, so it should look like

```
$('.post').each(function() {
  $(this).closest('.caption').css('height', $(this).height());
});
```

This may not work with `closest` (depending on your structure), but you've got the idea.

**EDIT**

From your update

use `next` instead of `closest`

```
$('.post').each(function() {
    $(this).next('.caption').height($(this).height());
});
```

Comment: '.caption' is not child of '.post', should it be to make it work?

Comment: @user3052619 it does not have to, but without seeing a HTML snippet of your structure it's hard to guess

Comment: @user3052619 you don't need to change your DOM, but we have to know it to find the right function (which may or may not be `closest`). Try to put a sample on jsfiddle...

Comment: Still not, I don't know why it doesn't work. Thank you anyway, I will keep trying!

Comment: With "closest" and "next" the height of the '.caption' doesn't even change. It's strange, maybe it's because is a tumblr blog

Comment: @user3052619 did you use height() instead of css() ?

Comment: Yes. Instead of that I will make the height of '.entry' same as the '.post' and set the overflow hidden. It's not a clean solution but.. Thank you for your interest again!

Comment: Finally found a solution starting from your answer!